# ETL into SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

Forgive me if this is a double post. I am new here and thought I asked. Anyway, I know you can pull data from SQL into SharePoint, but I need to pull data from 2 separate places, and do transformations. This would be ongoing, so I need to update SP, not a one time pull. Example : users want a gift list, with company name, company address, total number of order and total order revenue. The names come from contact table in database1, orders come from order table in database2. I am not a farm admin, just a power user, and only have read access to the databases. What are some ways to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can use Business Data Connectivity service in SharePoint to get the table directly from SQL database.

However you will need to configure it first. As you mention you are not an admin, just a power user, I assume you have no access to Admin Center. So you will not be able to do anything if the service has not been configured.

Steps which you can refer to:
https://zimmergren.net/sp-2010-getting-started-with-business-connectivity-services-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee556407(v=office.14)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7559.sharepoint-2010-how-to-configure-business-data-connectivity-service.aspx

Comment: Hello. I know about BCS. It doesnt allow you to add any columns to the list, nor allow transformation.